# How to write a console application text into a txt

Tags: c#, console, console-application, dump, streamwriter

Im making a tool that uses procdump to dump a process then uses Strings v2.53 to convert the dump to actual strings, after converting the dump I am trying to write all the strings that are displayed in the console application into a .txt.

I have no clue what im doing wrong and ive tried every forum post ive see on how to do do this and I just cant do it.

heres my code

```
        string path2 = @"C:\Void\Dump\Dump.txt";


        Process p = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
        info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
        info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        info.UseShellExecute = false;

        p.StartInfo = info;
        p.Start();
        StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
        using (sw)
        {
            if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Void\Dump");
                sw.WriteLine(@"strings -s");

                System.IO.StreamWriter stream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path2);

                sw.AutoFlush = true;

                Console.SetOut(stream);

            }
        }
```

Comment: I just need to know how to convert the text that the Console App is writing into a txt.

Comment: What is your end goal? What do you want to do with the txt file? If you want to read back that txt in your program again, you could also just start strings.exe directly as process without needing a detour via cmd.exe. If you do so, you can just redirect the StandardOutput of this process and read the output of strings.exe entirely programmatically in your C# program without needing a temporary txt file...

Comment: I making a tool that will automatically create a dump of the javaw process, convert the dump to readable strings using strings.exe, then searches the new txt with the consoleapp strings for Cheat related strings. Because the people I work for dont want cheaters on there network, so they want me to make a tool to prevent that. I already have the process of the making of the dumps and converting it. I just need to know how to convert all of the displayed ConsoleApp text into a txt that I can then search.

Comment: So essentially you do want to have the output from strings.exe to be searched in your program, or do i misunderstand you?

Comment: yes, you are exactly correct.

Comment: Then you might try my suggestion in my first comment (just ignore the parts about the txt). Start strings.exe directly (without cmd.exe) and redirect its StandardOutput. The redirected StandardOutput is then available to your program through a TextReader provided by the Process object  (See documentation of `Process` and `ProcessStartInfo` for more details about redirecting StandardOutput).

Comment: By the way, if you only want to process only that single dump file through strings.exe it is better  to avoid the -s parameter. Instead, pass the absolute path to the dump file as argument for strings.exe (since the path can contain white-spaces, make sure that the path string used as argument contains quote characters as first and last character inside the string.

Comment: I cant do that. you need to start the string.exe process with cmd and you need to use the cmd to run commands through strings.exe

Comment: Could you explain why you would need to run strings.exe with cmd?

Comment: I already have the code to create the dump and view the dump as strings in the Console Application. i just need to convert the Console app text to a txt ( dump.txt ) and i also have code to remove un necessary strings as well

Comment: You didn't answer my question. strings.exe does not require cmd.exe to operate. And you also don't run commands through strings.exe (you only provide arguments to strings.exe and it does its thing. I feel you misunderstand how the `Process` class works, but i fear we won't resolve this misunderstanding here. Perhaps some time with a tutorial covering the `Process` class would help a bit...

Comment: I understand what your trying to say. But im trying to say that I dont really need any of that. I just need to know how to create a new txt that contains all the text from console application because I already have everything else setup. i just have no clue how to Write all the Console Application text into a txt.

Comment: Okay, now i am confused :) Could you show how you would in your case use strings.exe with the txt's on the command line in a cmd window? (so i can get an idea what you really want to do, and how this would translate into some C# code using Process)

Comment: And i have to run it in CMD to run the commands along with the tool. ive only been using strings.exe for like 6 hrs. i dont really know anything about it. thats why i dont know how to convert the text it generates into a txt.

Comment: You don't need to run the CD command i see in your code. ProcessStartInfo itself has a property that can be used to set the working directory when the process is started.

Comment: You cant directly open strings ( i dont think, ive tried ). Si i have cmd open the strings, do the commands, write the strings it generates in the the console application, then im trying to convert the console application text into a txt, OR somehow save the text strings.exe generates into a txt.

Comment: It would probably better if you first start trying to get strings.exe working with your files in a cmd window. If you have a command line with strings.exe working in a cmd window, you can start adapting/transferring it into your C# program for using it with Process class...

Comment: Long story short. im trying to get strings.exe to read a dump, then somehow get the text it reads put into a txt. thats all i need.

Comment: I said it multiple times: strings.exe is just simple exe that can be directly opened/started without cmd.exe. I don't know what you do there, but it is something i can't help you with because i have no clue whatsoever what sort of mistake(s) happen(ed) that could possibly make you think that strings.exe cannot be run/started/opened on its own. I am sorry, but i am at a loss here. I don't know how to help you... :(

Comment: Ill explain all the steps im wanting to do to get the txt that contains the strings that strings.exe generates

1. I use proc dump to dump javaw process
2. I use CMD to set the file path of where the dump is
3. use CMD to start strings.exe and change the dump into readable strings
4. Somehow get a txt made that contains all of the text strings.exe converted.

Comment: I know that strings.exe can directly be ran. But thats not what i need help with. im not making my tool run it directly. i just need to know how to get the strings that are in a console application converted into a txt.

Comment: I already have strings.exe working how i want it to. i just need to get the text it generates into a txt. Whether thats getting strings.exe to( if thats possible ) or Getting all of the console application text converted to a txt

Answer (score 1):

I would build this so that you are writing to the text file as you are writing to the console output.

```
File.WriteAllText(fileDirectoryPath, textData);//is the simplest way you can write to a file
```

You will also need to convert stream to text with a streamreader before sending into the textData parameter of WriteAllText. See example below:

```
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
string text = reader.ReadToEnd();
File.WriteAllText("pathwayToDirectory", text);
```

And here is the code integrated into your solution. Note I am assuming you are putting this text data in the dump file:

```
   string path2 = @"C:\Void\Dump\Dump.txt";


    Process p = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
    info.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    info.RedirectStandardInput = true;
    info.UseShellExecute = false;

    p.StartInfo = info;
    p.Start();
    StreamWriter sw = p.StandardInput;
    using (sw)
    {
        if (sw.BaseStream.CanWrite)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(@"cd C:\Void\Dump");
            sw.WriteLine(@"strings -s");

            System.IO.StreamWriter stream = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path2);

              StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path2);//Fixed this to have the right value
            string text = reader.ReadToEnd();//convert stream to text
            File.WriteAllText(path2, text);

            Console.SetOut(stream);
            sw.AutoFlush = true;

        }
    }
```

Comment: Theres an error on the like where you try to declare 'reader' http://prntscr.com/kx8lem

But to get a bit more detailed with what im trying to do.

After the console application converts the dump to strings, the strings are visible in the console application. So I am trying to create a whole new txt that contains all of the text within the console application.